# iPhone 5s with question on calendar

Tags: iphone

I started a new calendar. Can anyone get in and see my appointments? This is my private calendar to make my appointments. I am starting new job I want to make sure that old boss can't see anything.

Comment: your best choice is to use the online Google Calendar that your Boos can not get to.

Answer (score 1):

If the old boss doesn't have your AppleID & password & you don't explicitly share the calendar, no-one can see it.

You could always change your password if you are in the slightest doubt over that & also sign in to https://www.icloud.com/#settings select Advanced/Data & Security, then Sign out of all browsers.

[image]